# vue-multiselect dropdown list without horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, multi-select

I'm using vue-multiselect in single-select mode and trying to apply styles to make options dropdown list be same width as most wide option. I achieved this, but can't get .multiselect__option be same width as parent .multiselect__element:

https://jsfiddle.net/xo9f7jby/30/

```
.multiselect {
    width: fit-content
}

.multiselect__content-wrapper, .multiselect__element {
    width: fit-content; 
}

.multiselect__option {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple solution would be to remove `fit-content` from `.multiselect__element`:

```css
.multiselect__content-wrapper /*, .multiselect__element */ {
  width: fit-content; 
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xo9f7jby/33/

Answer (score 0):

**I just comment the position in the class as u see**

```css
.multiselect__content-wrapper {
  /*position:absolute;*/
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 240px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 50;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
}
```